# Android : parsing large json response

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using google [gson-2.2.1](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.2-release.zip) library for parsing large response of JSON.

I have to parse a JSON response where structure may vary.

First case, when the response contains more than one team:

```
 "Details":{

           "Role":"abc",
           "Team":[
              {
                 "active":"yes",
                 "primary":"yes",
                 "content":"abc"
              },
              {
                 "active":"yes",
                 "primary":"yes",
                 "content":"xyz"
              }
           ],
```

Second case, when only one team is passed:

```
"Details":{

           "Role":"abc",
           "Team":
              {
                 "active":"yes",
                 "primary":"yes",
                 "content":"abc"
              }
}
```

There are my base classes used for parsing:

```
class Details {
    public String Role;
    public ArrayList<PlayerTeams> Team = new ArrayList<PlayerTeams>();
        PlayerTeams Team; // when JsonObject
}

class PlayerTeams {
    public String active;
    public String primary;
    public String content;
}
```

The problem is that I can not use `ArrayList<PlayerTeams>` when I have only one of them and it's returned as JsonObject.

Gson can identify static format of JSON response. I can trace full response dynamically by checking if "Team" key is instance of `JsonArray` or `JsonObject` but it would be great if a better solution is available for that.

**Edit :**
If my response is more dynamic..

```
"Details":{

       "Role":"abc",
       "Team":
          {
             "active":"yes",
             "primary":"yes",
             "content":"abc"
             "Test":
             {
                 "key1":"value1",
                 "key2":"value2",
                 "key3":"value3"
             }
          }
}
```

In my edited question, I am facing problem while my response is more dynamic..`Team` and `Test` can be `JsonArray` or `JsonObject`.. It really harassing me because sometime `Test` object may array when more data, may object when single data, string when no data. There is no consistency in response.

Comment: If you read JSONArray instead of JSONObject what happens? did you get any exception or null?

Comment: Google Gson throws exception if you use ArrayList for JsonObject..

Comment: The you can try reading JSONObject in catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a type adapter. This adapter would be able to distinguish which format is coming and instance the right object with the right values.

You can do this by:

1. implement your own type adapter by creating a class that implements `JsonSerializer<List<Team>>, JsonDeserializer<List<Team>>`, of course `JsonSerializer` is just needed in case you need to serialize it in that matter too.
2. Register the type adapter to you `GsonBuilder` like: `new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<List<Team>>() {}.getType(), new CoupleAdapter()).create()`

The deserialize method could look like:

```
public List<Team> deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws com.google.gson.JsonParseException {
    if (json.isJsonObject()) {
        return Collections.singleton(context.deserialize(json, Team.class));
    } else {
        return context.deserialize(json, typeOfT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I register two or more `TypeAdapter` for large response. I tried and goes to infinitr loop. because deserialize called infinitely. I tested